# Bootstrap fluid container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im after a point in the right direction with a query on fluid containers for the bootstrap framework. I have attached a visual of what I'm trying to create. I need two fluid rows of 2 columns but i need the content to keep to the standard container rules. I want to keep it as simple as possible without complicated css backgrounds or gradients.

Im hoping this is a simple query. I have never come across the need to do this with bootstrap before.

[image]

Comment: you could trick it abit by using offset on the content behind, and fake the front containers with slight css differences (the borders etc)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the usual Bootstrap container and `col-*` and then use absolute position pseudo elements for the color block backgrounds..

HTML

```
<div class="container border">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row margin-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 a"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 b"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 c"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 d"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a:after {
  margin:0 15px 15px;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  display:block;
  background:#9999cc;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
  width:200%;
}
.b:after {
  margin:0 0 15px 0;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  display:block;
  background:#aa99cc;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
  width:200%;
}
.c:after {
  margin:0 15px 0;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  display:block;
  background:#cc2299;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
  width:200%;
}
.d:after {
  margin:0;    
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  display:block;
  background:#aaeecc;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
  width:200%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/OAdlxM3jKb

Comment: The trouble with this solution is that the blocks that are positioned are off the screen and as a result they force the page to scroll on the horizontal axis so although it renders, it has scroll which isn't ideal

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, since all measurements are made in percentages, so they are relative to the parent container that are inserted.

My suggestion would be to place the columns where you want to really stay, and then would make this real container be in absolute position, floating on the other brown and blue.

Comment: Do you have a working solution you would like to share with me?